# Why does Multiprocessing spawn multiple PyGame instances?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a simulation program, but it gets very slow with large lists. I decided to use the Multiprocessing module and map() my calculations to speed up the rendering I do with PyGame.

I have the 'calculation.py' that runs the calculations and contains the Multiprocessing separate to the 'main.py' script, and I just import 'calculation.py' and pass my values through to the 'calculation.py' script.

So my hierarchy is:

> --> Project
>
> > --> calculation.py (does the map() and returns values)
> >
> > --> main.py (draws the values received in PyGame)

However, when I run the calculations in 'calculation.py', I end up spawning multiple PyGame windows, even though I haven't even imported PyGame into 'calculation.py'

I want my 'calculation.py' to just take the values given by 'main.py', run the calculations with the Multiprocessing map() function, then return the values to 'main.py', and have 'main.py' draw on a Pygame window.

Let me know if you want me to clarify anything!

EDIT: Here is some pseudo-code from each file:

main.py:

```py
from calculation import calculate

#Assume there is a person class which contains info about each 'i' in the list such as their coordinates

infected = [person(i) for i in range(1)] 
healthy = [i for i in range(1000)

#Pygame initialization
#....
#....

if __name__=='__main__':
    while(True):
        healthy,infected = calculate(healthy,infected)
```

calculation.py:

```py
def check(i):
    for j in healthy:
        if i.isinradius(j) and j.getsinfected(): #does some probability
            infected.append(j)
            healthy.remove(j)


def calculation(h,infected):
    global healthy
    healthy = h
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(check,infected)
    return healthy,infected
```

Comment: Multiprocessing defaults to using `fork()` of the current process, making a copy of it. Make your calculation a stand-alone program, and use something like `subprocess.popen()` to spawn it. Or maybe you can use `multiprocessing.spawn()`

Comment: @Kingsley I can't seem to find any documentation on multiprocessing.spawn().

Comment: Please see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods.  My comment has the syntax incorrect, It's `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')`